# Adjusting inequalities in a dataframe and changing value to become a numeric based on a given desired value

Tags: r, data-wrangling

I'm trying to wrangle the data here by adjusting certain values in a data frame.

I have to use plots that cannot use character symbols in my data. Is there a way where I can replace data below with those inequality symbols with a numerical value, such that the column in that data frame becomes numeric?

[image]

The photo has my data frame and goal to achieve.

(I apologize for adding a photo, the question box didn't like something I added into the box it seemed)

Is there an efficient way to do this on R without having to manually change each data point on excel or something?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: so values without `>` or `<` should just be kept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `dplyr` Package to manipulate the data.frame
with [`mutate()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/mutate.html).

You could utilize regular expressions (regex) to search the character `test_score` for entries that starts with a `>` or `<`  with: `grepl("^>",test_score)`

and use `ifelse` to
either instead write `'100'` or `'0'` in the corresponding cell. If the character does not start with < or > you can just keep the old value with `test_score`

```
# Create Minimal Reproducible Example
DF1 <- data.frame(SampleID = paste0("Subject",c(1:5)), 
                  test_score=c(">90",">90","<50","<50","67"))


library(dplyr)
DF1 %>%
  mutate(test_score_converted = ifelse(grepl("^>",test_score),100,
                                       ifelse(grepl("^<",test_score),0,
                                              test_score))) %>% 
  mutate(test_score_converted = as.numeric(test_score_converted))
```

Output:

```
  SampleID test_score test_score_converted
1 Subject1        >90                  100
2 Subject2        >90                  100
3 Subject3        <50                    0
4 Subject4        <50                    0
5 Subject5         67                   67
```

Please note that the code above also converts to a numeric value (instead of a character). If you have other special characters in the column test_score, the code will fail. You can then either additionally remove all non digit characters with another regex like this `gsub("\\D","",DF1$test_score)` or just comment out the second  `%>% mutate()` in the example above that does the conversion to numeric values

Answer (score 1):

Convert the values in `test_score` column to numbers using `parse_number`, then use `case_when` to check for various conditions and assign output.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  mutate(score_num = readr::parse_number(test_score), 
         final_score = case_when(grepl('>', test_score) & score_num >= 90 ~ 100, 
                                 grepl('<', test_score) & score_num <= 50 ~ 0, 
                                 #...add more conditions if needed
                                 TRUE ~ score_num))

#  SampleID test_score score_num final_score
#1 Subject1        >90        90         100
#2 Subject2        >90        90         100
#3 Subject3        <50        50           0
#4 Subject4        <50        50           0
#5 Subject5         67        67          67
```